# Google App Engine dns_get_record

Tags: php, google-app-engine, dns

I am getting a fatal error that "Call to undefined function dns_get_record" in the live environment when making a dns_get_record request but it works fine in the Google App Engine SDK environment.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine lists the details of their PHP runtime environment here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

dns_get_records is a built in function in all versions of PHP since 5.0 for performing DNS lookups in code.

Unfortunately Google has not documented it but the PHP src they are compiling against appears to disable the dns_get_record function.

You are out of luck.

Comment: Socket functions are only available to apps that have billing enabled. Does your app have billing enabled?

Comment: Yes, billing is enabled and has been for about a month now. To confirm, I am being billed for MySQL as well as SSL and have a credit applied to the account as well.

Comment: Then it's a bug and not intentional. If possible can you create an issue in the tracker? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Defect

Comment: I submitted a code Stuart, thanks for all the hard work by you and the GAE team.